# Android Getting lag when loading items to a list view

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview that loads images form urls

I get lag when when images are out of view. Meaning the ones That i have to scroll to see, seems to be loading from the internet while I am trying to scroll to them.

How can I let the listview load all my images at first run?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for those who have a similar problem:

The [Glide Library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) could help with it. I had this problem as well and I could solve it by using Glide. You can load an image like this:

```
Glide.with(mContext)
            .asDrawable()
            .load(mImageUrl)
            .into(mViewHolder.mImageView);
```